# How to print the function name of function pointer in a Kernel API?

Tags: c, kernel, function-pointers

Assume there is a function pointer (sock->ops->ioctl()) in kernel space.
Now how do I print the name of the function stored in this pointer using printk or any other method you know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get function's name from function's pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351134/how-to-get-functions-name-from-functions-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

As it is says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21877817/361177):

> In the Linux kernel, you can use directly "%pF" format of printk !
>
> ```
> void *func = &foo;
> printk("func: %pF at address: %p\n", func, func);
> ```

Also as you know that `printk` is involved, you may have used [some tools](http://www.google.com) to find [documentation](http://www.embedded-bits.co.uk/2010/printk-format-specifiers/) [about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141324/function-caller-in-linux-kernel).

Comment: %pF is only printing the address and not the name !

Comment: @user3486405 Nope, see [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt). It prints both the name and the address.

Answer (score 2):

Base on Orace's answer, you might try `%pS` instead of `%pF`. I've tested that `%pF` is not working in 5.10.x version of kernel, but `%pS` works. Furthermore, I found a related comment in `vsprintf.c` -

> "`%pf` and `%pF` were obsoleted and later removed in favor of `%ps` and `%pS`. Be careful when re-using these specifiers".